# How do I add extra fields to a YouTube API Browser Upload form?

Tags: zend-framework, youtube-api, gdata

I have a form to upload video to youtube with zend gdata youtube. the problem is the action url of the form must be the url upload returned by youtube.  and then I can not catch others form fields to store them in the database. even the next url returned only 2 vars. status and video id.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube Web services Example.

```
//Action in your Controller

public function testYoutubeAction(){
Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Gdata_YouTube");
try{`enter code here`

$YouTube = new Zend_Gdata_Youtube();
//Get the specific video
$video = $YouTube->getVideoEntry("NwrL9MV6jSk");
$this->view->video = $video;
}catch(Zend Service_Exception $e)
  { throw $e; 
  }
}
```

in test-youtube.phtml

```
h2>Favorite Video of All Time!</h2><br>
<?php
$title
= $this->video->getVideoTitle();
$uri
= $this->video->getVideoWatchPageUrl();
$description = $this->video->getVideoDescription();
$thumbnails = $this->video->getVideoThumbnails();
$duration = $this->video->getVideoDuration();
$thumbnail = $thumbnails[1]['url'];
?>
<table>
<tr><td><img src='<?php echo $thumbnail ?>' height=50 width=50></td>
<td valign="top"><a href='<?php echo $uri ?>'><?php echo $title ?></a><br>
Duration <?php echo $duration ?> sec</td>
</tr>
</table>
```